# Calculate distance from movement iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I would like to be able to calculate distance based upon movement, as in user taps a start button and then when they reach their destination they tap a stop button. The app would calculate the actual distance travelled between the two points.

I have the mapkit working in that I can get the start location and the map tracks movement I just need to add in the calculation of distance.

Is this possible? If so any sample code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well what you could do is, record the user's coordinates when he hits start. The record his coordinates when he hits stop. Then you could use the CoreLocation framework to calculate the distance between the two points.

```
distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
```

**EDIT**

I see now that you want the distance actually travelled by the person. I know that in the new IOS you can make use of the direction functionality, so what you could do is record the distance traveled every time the user changes the direction, and then add everything up when they hit STOP

**EDIT**

you can check out some of apple's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801)

Comment: Does that give distance travelled or as the crow flies distance?

Comment: that gives displacement...as in straight line from point a to point b

Comment: Is that only available in iOS5 I'm trying to support iOS 4.2.1 for 3G iPhone as well as newer iPhones. Presumably I can check for iOS 5 and only offer functionality if there?

Are there any code examples?

Comment: the 'course' property (which allows you to obtain the direction which the phone is travelling in) is available for xcode 2.2 and beyond...which xcode are you using to program?

Comment: you should be fine, check out what I posted and see if you can make it work

Comment: Ok so using the example I set the distance filter to say 10 meters that triggers the delegate and I can add those values up to get a total distance. When the user presses stop. I'm within a 10 meter accuracy? I guess I could check speed and increase or decreas the filter accordingly so that the updates are slower if moving at speed. Hopefully that makes sense. If so I can implement that. Thanks for your help.